# Why can we bias mosfet with current source

Tags: mosfet, biasing

[image]

I know that we can get desired DC current by supplying certain VGS asccording to the equation I=(1/2)*K(VGS-VT)^2.
But the scheme shown in the picture does it in a reversed way. It is establishing a VGS according to I.
Can this really happen? Doesn't Mosfet only transfer signal in one way (from gate to drain current)? How can it be the other around?

Comment: Yes it's fine. What happens is that the source voltage settles at whatever is needed to maintain Vgs for current I. Nothing is transferred to the input (gate) circuit.

Comment: What if the gate is floating? And I am biasing source with a voltage source. Will gate change to the desired voltage?

Comment: Those are different questions with different answers.

Comment: *What if the gate is floating?* You should not. Any circuit with a floating gate doesn't behave in a predictable way. You **MUST ALWAYS** define the gate voltage properly. *Will gate change to the desired voltage?* How can it when it is floating? And if you measured the gate voltage, the gate wouldn't be floating anymore, you would be connecting the gate to ground through the impedance of the voltmeter.